# es6 extend already defined class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, subclass

I have a `Base` class as

```
class Base {
    constructor() {
        console.log('should get called')
    }
}
```

and a `Target` class as

```
class Target {
    someFn() {
        // does something
    }
}
```

I want to make `Target` extend `Base` after its defined. I mean, I know I could simply do the following

```
class Target extends Base { ... }
```

However, I still want to be able to extend `Target` with `Base` after its defined.

I tried several ways, but not completely happy with it. Is that possible?

I could do `class Base extends Target {}` but then its not the same class anymore.

My basic objective is; I want to add `constructor` to a class (which I know I can't), so figuring out some ways.

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: Lol, good question... I don't know actually... :P Ok, I'll explain, I want to define lots of classes with some methods, each returning result of some calculation. The data (on which those formulae will operate) will be passed in the constructor (where I want to pre-process it)... So I want to keep formula classes clean with only formula methods, and do all other stuff in my decorator function or base class... Makes sense?

Comment: Your comment does not explain why you want to change the prototype dynamically. It does not even explain why you need inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

You can make an existing class "inherit" from another class by setting the prototype of the child class' prototype. Sounds a bit complicated, so here's all it takes:

```
class Base {}
class Child {}

Object.setPrototypeOf(Child.prototype, Base.prototype)
```

However, there is a gotcha: The `Child`'s implementation was not designed to inherit from another class - if, for example, the `Base` constructor is doing some important work (many times parent constructors do some initialisation steps) **this will not be called**, meaning, you may encounter all sorts of bugs.

In the context you describe, there is no viable solution to programmatically extend a class **and** ensure the parent class' constructor gets called. This is because there is no way to "patch" the child class' constructor function to actually invoke the parent class' constructor.

You may be tempted to override the `Child.prototype.constructor` property and patch it there, but the problem is that **this is not what is called** when you do `new Child()`, it's the `Child` function itself - the constructor property does not play a role in this process.

Comment: Nope, won't work... I've explained in the comment above.

Comment: Updated based on your updates. Unfortunately, I do not see a way to make this work. Sorry.

Comment: Sad... Thanks anyway.